# set value of hidden field by js get parameter

Tags: javascript, get, hidden-field

I trying to get a parameter via GET request and get these parameters to set the value of hidden fields.

the form is created via elementor pro.

I got an HTML block to the page and inserted the parameters to vars:

```
<script>
function getUrlVars() {
   var vars = {};
   var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
   vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
     }
   var refe = getUrlVars()["ref"];
   document.getElementById("form-field-b3bacc6").value = refe;
  });
</script>
```

the field is hidden if that matters...

but I can't get to change the value of the input field.

any guidance about what am I doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: What's the value of `refe`? Did you do *any* debugging so far? Is that script located above the hidden `<input>`? Because if so, it's running too early.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, and `refe` contains only numbers, the script is in the end of the page (so it'll have something to change)...

Comment: This isn't valid JS code right now, given the trailing `});` at the end. If I fix that, the rest works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/dpav8bc0/

Comment: thank you very much my friend! it works!
many thanks!